# Django-voting -- using two views for one webpage

Tags: django, django-voting

I have a page called `view_requests.html`. One one tab on the page, I'd like to have basically a list of objects reddit style that people can upvote. I accomplished this using `django-voting`.

However, on a second tab, I would like the ability to add a request. This requires that I have a form that people can submit.

The problem I'm facing is that to implement the Reddit style voting, I had to use the following configuration in my URLs.py (ie. not create my own view for it in views.py). But to create a form, I need to access some code I wrote in views.py. Is it possible to have both on the same page in separate tabs, and how would I go about doing this?

```
url(r'^view_requests/?$', object_list, dict(queryset=LibraryRequest.objects.all(),
        template_object_name='request', template_name='spicemodels/view_requests.html',
        paginate_by=15, allow_empty=True), name="view_requests"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to use that; `object_list` is a built-in Django *generic* view. Generic being the keyword, because it's merely intended to make it easier for you *if your view conforms to a standard*. Since, you need more from your view than `object_list` can provide, it's time to throw it out and write your own view. You can use [`object_list`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.1/django/views/generic/list_detail.py) as a guide for creating your own view, but there's a lot of extraneous boilerplate code in it just to make it generic. Simplistically, the following is all you need:

```
def my_view(request, page=None):
    paginate_by = 15

    qs = LibraryRequest.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(qs, paginate_by, allow_empty_first_page=True)
    if not page:
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        page_number = int(page)
    except ValueError:
        if page == 'last':
            page_number = paginator.num_pages
        else:
            # Page is not 'last', nor can it be converted to an int.
            raise Http404
    try:
        page_obj = paginator.page(page_number)
    except InvalidPage:
        raise Http404

    render_to_response('spicemodels/view_requests.html', {
        'request_list': page_obj.object_list,
        'paginator': paginator,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
        'is_paginated': page_obj.has_other_pages(),
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that `object_list` was generic (thought it was specific to `django-voting`). I have actually been creating them in the way you described above for every other page.